# Properly parenting a "follow path set up" to an empty

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, parent

I try to parent a set up of cube parented to an empty wich is following a curve with a constraint to a "global" empty. And I don't find a solution that allow me to move my empty and keep the initial offset between parented objects. Do you have an idea of how can I do it?

EDIT : To be clearer, I need to find a trick to set up only one global parent object  that allow me to manipulate scale/rot/location of all other objects without breaking initial offset.

[Blend File](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/422794267216576516/899421270930784296/followPathParenting.blend)

[image: parented curve+follow path]

Answer (score 1):

Unparent *EmptyFollowPath* from *Empty For ALL*, the *Follow Path* constraint already acts like a parentage, if you parent to *Empty For ALL* it will push *EmptyFollowPath* away from the curve.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It was obvious to me but maybe I should say that my point is to manipulate scale/rot/loc off all object with one parent. If I unparent the EmptyFollowPath from Empty For ALL I won't be able to scale all my objects with the global empty.

Comment: so in that case maybe give it a Copy Scale constraint?

Comment: Excellent! I was writing the same answer while you answered :)
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that allow me to manipulate all transforms of all objects even the scale of the empty that follow the curve with only one parent.

1. dont parent constrained empty
2. add "copy scale" constraint to this empty and pick the "global empty" as target.

I would prefer that all object was packed into one parent in oultiner but it's OK like that.